# How to solve StackInbalance

Tags: vb.net

I Have the following code inside of a DLL:

```
 Public Class MouseHook
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As MouseProcDelegate, ByVal hmod As Integer, ByVal dwThreadId As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Integer) As Integer
    Private Delegate Function MouseProcDelegate(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
    Private Structure MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Public pt As Point
        Public mouseData As Integer
        Public flags As Integer
        Public time As Integer
        Public dwExtraInfo As Integer
    End Structure
    Public Enum Wheel_Direction
        WheelUp
        WheelDown
    End Enum

    Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL As Integer = 14
    Private Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONUP As Integer = &H202
    Private Const WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H203
    Private Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H204
    Private Const WM_RBUTTONUP As Integer = &H205
    Private Const WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H206
    Private Const WM_MBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H207
    Private Const WM_MBUTTONUP As Integer = &H208
    Private Const WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK As Integer = &H209
    Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Integer = &H20A

    Private MouseHook As Integer
    Private MouseHookDelegate As MouseProcDelegate

    Public Event Mouse_Move(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Left_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Left_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Left_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Right_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Right_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Right_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Middle_Down(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Middle_Up(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Middle_DoubleClick(ByVal ptLocat As Point)
    Public Event Mouse_Wheel(ByVal ptLocat As Point, ByVal Direction As Wheel_Direction)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' A WindowHandle a következő változóval nyerhető ki: Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>Csak akkor működik, ha a WindowHandle már létezik</remarks>
    ''' 
    Public Sub New(windowHandle As Integer)
        MouseHookDelegate = New MouseProcDelegate(AddressOf MouseProc)
        MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookDelegate, windowHandle, 0)
    End Sub
    Private Function MouseProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_MOUSEMOVE
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Move(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_Down(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_LBUTTONUP
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_Up(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Left_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_Down(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_RBUTTONUP
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_Up(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Right_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_MBUTTONDOWN
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_Down(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_MBUTTONUP
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_Up(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Middle_DoubleClick(lParam.pt)
                Case WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                    Dim wDirection As Wheel_Direction
                    If lParam.mouseData < 0 Then
                        wDirection = Wheel_Direction.WheelDown
                    Else
                        wDirection = Wheel_Direction.WheelUp
                    End If
                    RaiseEvent Mouse_Wheel(lParam.pt, wDirection)
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook)
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I call this on an other project, with the DLL referenced:

```
Public Class Form1
 Private WithEvents mHook As MouseHook
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mHook = New MouseHook(Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
End Class
```

But I get the following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to
> PInvoke function
> 'BarcodeTestApp!BarcodeTestApp.Form1+MouseHook::CallNextHookEx' has
> unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
> signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
> the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
> the target unmanaged signature.'

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: In realase build i don't seem to get the exception :/

Comment: CallNextHookEx is taking MLLSTRUCT by value, is that correct?  More generally, where did you get the API declarations?

Comment: That warning tells you that your CallNextHookEx() declaration is wrong.  Pass the struct `ByRef`.  There are a lot more mistakes that are going to byte when you run this program in 64-bit mode.  Consider using a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook).